# Facebook Graph API: 400 Bad Request when getting user data

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I'm making a page that displays details of an event, and details of any user that has registered an interest in coming to that event. I am using Facebook's Python-SDK (https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk) and I have had no problem getting the access token of the currently logged-in user. However, when the user visits this page of event details, the intention is that they can see names and profile pics of the users involved in this event. I use this code to populate this list of users:

```
for liftoffer in self.liftoffers:
            if (liftoffer.user.key() == dbuser.key()):
                self.hasliftoffer = True
                self.template_values['myliftoffer'] = liftoffer
            logging.warn("Request: fbuser = graph.get_object(%s, fields=\"name, picture, username\")" % str(liftoffer.user.fbid))
            logging.warn("access_token: %s" % self.current_user.access_token)
            fbuser = graph.get_object(str(liftoffer.user.fbid), fields="name, picture, username")
            newuser = ListUser(fbuser['name'], fbuser['picture'], fbuser['username'], liftoffer.user.key())
            self.drivers.append(newuser)
```

The graph has already been defined at this point using:

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(self.current_user.access_token)
```

Here is the error I get:

```
ERROR    2011-04-27 17:45:42,007 __init__.py:427] HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py", line 634, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "/Users/wadben/Documents/Dev/Python/facebook-python-sdk-322930c/examples/oauth/sp-oauth-local/sparewheels.py", line 83, in get
    self.get_secure()
  File "/Users/wadben/Documents/Dev/Python/facebook-python-sdk-322930c/examples/oauth/sp-oauth-local/sparewheels.py", line 485, in get_secure
    fbuser = graph.get_object(str(liftoffer.user.fbid), fields="name, picture, username")
  File "/Users/wadben/Documents/Dev/Python/facebook-python-sdk-322930c/examples/oauth/sp-oauth-local/facebook.py", line 88, in get_object
    return self.request(id, args)
  File "/Users/wadben/Documents/Dev/Python/facebook-python-sdk-322930c/examples/oauth/sp-oauth-local/facebook.py", line 172, in request
    urllib.urlencode(args), post_data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 121, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 380, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 491, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 418, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 353, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 499, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

The logging lines show me that the request took in a valid Facebook ID and access_token, so I don't understand what is going wrong here. Is it not possible to get the picture and username of other Facebook users apart from the one currently logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4824